# consume -kafka processor is not working on nifi UI?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

​Got stuck into this simple problem for last two days nothing worked for me.

The case is quite simple.Here is the case

> " On nifi UI consume-kafka shows nothing although on a terminal
>   kafka-consumer-console showing successful consumption of data " .

[image]

please do suggest me the solution.Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you're trying to consume from both the NiFi processor and the console consumer simultaneously, the messages may not come through. Can you try with the console consumer stopped and giving a different `Group ID`?

Comment: @M.WAQAS JAMIL Did the above suggestion work for you?